# sed: find and replace string but not super-string

Tags: sed

I have a file `env` which looks like

....

```
LEGACY_DATABASE_SERVER=10.0.0.1
SERVER=10.1.1.1
```

and here is my sed command:

`sed -e "s/SERVER=.*/SERVER=$INSTANCE_IP/g;n" $ENV_FILE > $ENV_FILE.tmp && mv $ENV_FILE.tmp $ENV_FILE`

the problem is that `sed` is also replacing `LEGACY_DATABASE_SERVER` which is not what I want. I only want `SERVER` replaced.

(LEGACY_DATABASE_SERVER is a super string of SERVER and I only want to replace SERVER)

What am I missing?

Comment: `sed` has an in place option instead of doing all that temp file stuff at the end. It's -i.

Comment: tried that a while ago. I'm on OSX. I get this error sed: 1: "env": invalid command code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you want to make sure that sed knows "SERVER" is at the beginning of the line:

```
sed -e "s/^SERVER=.*/SERVER=$INSTANCE_IP/g;n" $ENV_FILE > $ENV_FILE.tmp && mv $ENV_FILE.tmp $ENV_FILE
```